# Trouble getting WebVTT captions/subtitles working on Chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm working on a Chromecast app for Android, and trying to get WebVTT captions/subtitles working.

I instantiate a MediaTrack object as follows:

```
            MediaTrack track = new MediaTrack.Builder(0, MediaTrack.TYPE_TEXT)
                .setContentId("http://www.example.com/example.vtt")
                .setSubtype(MediaTrack.SUBTYPE_SUBTITLES)
                .setContentType("ISO-8859-1")
                .setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH)
                .setName("English")
                .build();
```

and add it to a list.

I instantiate MediaInfo using the builder, and include reference the list of tracks using the .setMediaTracks method:

```
MediaInfo.Builder builder = new MediaInfo.Builder("http://www.example.com/example.m3u8")
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                .setContentType("application/vnd.apple.mpegurl")
                .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
                .setMediaTracks(mediaTracks).build();
```

In my app I then start the CastControllerActivity that comes with the companion library:

```
mCastManager.startCastControllerActivity(this, mSelectedMedia, position, autoPlay);
```

After I've done this I set the active media track (only one in my case), and the text track style:

```
long [] activeTracks = new long[1];
activeTracks[0] = 0l;
mCastManager.getRemoteMediaPlayer()
        .setActiveMediaTracks(mCastManager.getGoogleApiClient(), activeTracks)
        .setResultCallback(new MediaResultCallback());
mCastManager.getRemoteMediaPlayer().setTextTrackStyle(
        mCastManager.getGoogleApiClient(),
        TextTrackStyle.fromSystemSettings(getBaseContext()));
```

When playing a clip containing subtitles the console shows the following:

```
[775.223s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Too many track IDs cast_receiver.js:18
[775.232s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Invalid track IDs cast_receiver.js:18
[775.238s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending error: INVALID_REQUEST INVALID_PARAMS
```

and the status code in the returned ResultCallback is SERVICE_MISSING - even though Google Play Services 5.0.89 is installed on both Android 4.4 devices I'm using when developing. The subtitles are hosted with CORS headers.

Any ideas or pointers?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that CCL has not yet been updated to handle Tracks (it is an upcoming feature). CCL builds a Bundle from MediaInfo and uses that bundle when firing the CastControllerActivity to pass the MediaInfo (MediaInfo is not parcelable, hence have to use a wrapper and a Bundle is one solution). In the exiting CCL, when it creates a bundle, it doesn't consider Tracks, hence the bundle doesn't have the tracks info. As a result, you are practically loading a media (since it happens in the CastControllerActivity) that doesn't have any tracks info, hence the error that you see.

Till Tracks support gets added to CCL, you can do the following. In Utils class, update the two methods `fromMediaInfo()` and `toMediaInfo()` with the following codes in the CCL itself:

```
private static final String KEY_TRACK_ID = "track-id";
private static final String KEY_TRACK_CONTENT_ID = "track-custom-id";
private static final String KEY_TRACK_NAME = "track-name";
private static final String KEY_TRACK_TYPE = "track-type";
private static final String KEY_TRACK_SUBTYPE = "track-subtype";
private static final String KEY_TRACK_LANGUAGE = "track-language";
private static final String KEY_TRACK_CUSTOM_DATA = "track-custom-data";
private static final String KEY_TRACKS_DATA = "track-data";

public static Bundle fromMediaInfo(MediaInfo info) {
    if (null == info) {
        return null;
    }

    MediaMetadata md = info.getMetadata();
    Bundle wrapper = new Bundle();
    wrapper.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, md.getString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE));
    wrapper.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, md.getString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE));
    wrapper.putString(KEY_URL, info.getContentId());
    wrapper.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_STUDIO, md.getString(MediaMetadata.KEY_STUDIO));
    wrapper.putString(KEY_CONTENT_TYPE, info.getContentType());
    wrapper.putInt(KEY_STREAM_TYPE, info.getStreamType());
    if (!md.getImages().isEmpty()) {
        ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (WebImage img : md.getImages()) {
            urls.add(img.getUrl().toString());
        }
        wrapper.putStringArrayList(KEY_IMAGES, urls);
    }
    JSONObject customData = info.getCustomData();
    if (null != customData) {
        wrapper.putString(KEY_CUSTOM_DATA, customData.toString());
    }

    if (null != info.getMediaTracks() && !info.getMediaTracks().isEmpty()) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            for (MediaTrack mt : info.getMediaTracks()) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put(KEY_TRACK_NAME, mt.getName());
                jsonObject.put(KEY_TRACK_CONTENT_ID, mt.getContentId());
                jsonObject.put(KEY_TRACK_ID, mt.getId());
                jsonObject.put(KEY_TRACK_LANGUAGE, mt.getLanguage());
                jsonObject.put(KEY_TRACK_TYPE, mt.getType());
                jsonObject.put(KEY_TRACK_SUBTYPE, mt.getSubtype());
                if (null != mt.getCustomData()) {
                    jsonObject.put(KEY_TRACK_CUSTOM_DATA, mt.getCustomData().toString());
                }
                jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
            }
            wrapper.putString(KEY_TRACKS_DATA, jsonArray.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            LOGE(TAG, "fromMediaInfo(): Failed to convert Tracks data to json", e);
        }
    }

    return wrapper;
}

public static MediaInfo toMediaInfo(Bundle wrapper) {
    if (null == wrapper) {
        return null;
    }

    MediaMetadata metaData = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);

    metaData.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE,
            wrapper.getString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE));
    metaData.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, wrapper.getString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE));
    metaData.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_STUDIO, wrapper.getString(MediaMetadata.KEY_STUDIO));
    ArrayList<String> images = wrapper.getStringArrayList(KEY_IMAGES);
    if (null != images && !images.isEmpty()) {
        for (String url : images) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            metaData.addImage(new WebImage(uri));
        }
    }
    String customDataStr = wrapper.getString(KEY_CUSTOM_DATA);
    JSONObject customData = null;
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(customDataStr)) {
        try {
            customData = new JSONObject(customDataStr);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            LOGE(TAG, "Failed to deserialize the custom data string: custom data= "
                    + customDataStr, e);
        }
    }
    List<MediaTrack> mediaTracks = null;
    if (null != wrapper.getString(KEY_TRACKS_DATA)) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(wrapper.getString(KEY_TRACKS_DATA));
            mediaTracks = new ArrayList<MediaTrack>();
            if (null != jsonArray && jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                    MediaTrack.Builder builder = new MediaTrack.Builder(
                            jsonObj.getLong(KEY_TRACK_ID), jsonObj.getInt(KEY_TRACK_TYPE));
                    if (jsonObj.has(KEY_TRACK_NAME)) {
                        builder.setName(jsonObj.getString(KEY_TRACK_NAME));
                    }
                    if (jsonObj.has(KEY_TRACK_SUBTYPE)) {
                        builder.setSubtype(jsonObj.getInt(KEY_TRACK_SUBTYPE));
                    }
                    if (jsonObj.has(KEY_TRACK_CONTENT_ID)) {
                        builder.setContentId(jsonObj.getString(KEY_TRACK_CONTENT_ID));
                    }
                    if (jsonObj.has(KEY_TRACK_LANGUAGE)) {
                        builder.setLanguage(jsonObj.getString(KEY_TRACK_LANGUAGE));
                    }
                    if (jsonObj.has(KEY_TRACKS_DATA)) {
                        builder.setCustomData(
                                new JSONObject(jsonObj.getString(KEY_TRACKS_DATA)));
                    }
                    mediaTracks.add(builder.build());
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            LOGE(TAG, "Failed to build media tracks from the wrapper bundle", e);
        }
    }
    return new MediaInfo.Builder(wrapper.getString(KEY_URL))
            .setStreamType(wrapper.getInt(KEY_STREAM_TYPE))
            .setContentType(wrapper.getString(KEY_CONTENT_TYPE))
            .setMetadata(metaData)
            .setCustomData(customData)
            .setMediaTracks(mediaTracks)
            .build();
}
```

This should hopefully solve your issue.

Comment: Using the methods the callback now returns SUCCESS, and there is no error in the developer console. However I'm not seeing any text. See the contents of the wrapper bundle in my next comment. Have you got any advice on how to proceed? Is there any way to enable more debug info in the (styled) receiver?

Comment: Contents of Bundle (note that StackOverflow strips away the http part of the URLs) :
[{movie-urls=http://www.example.com/example.m3u8, images=[http://www.example.com/1.jpg, http://www.example.com/2.jpg], com.google.android.gms.cast.metadata.TITLE=Title, com.google.android.gms.cast.metadata.SUBTITLE=, content-type=application/vnd.apple.mpegurl, track-data=[{"track-name":"English","track-custom-id":"http://www.example.com/example.vtt","track-id":0,"track-language":"en","track-type":1,"track-subtype":1}], stream-type=1}]

Comment: I wrote up a simple custom receiver based on the CastClosedCaptioning-sample, and it seems like the data gets through to the receiver as it should. See the following: http://pastebin.com/KpvByRD4

Comment: You can enable debugging in the styled/default receiver (same as yours) by calling this in s debug console: cast.receiver.logger.setLevelValue(cast.receiver.LoggerLevel.DEBUG); that should give us more clues as to what is going wrong.

Comment: The log you have there shows you loaded media but I don't see any line around where you are setting the active track.

Comment: Still I don't see any message in the console saying that receiver has "received" a message to set the active track.

Comment: Trying again. Hopefully this contains what you're looking for: http://pastebin.com/cMjvd2N0

Comment: Ok, that has the message I was looking for. Do you wait for the media to load before setting the active tracks?

Comment: Yes. For the app I'm working on the user has to enable subtitles every time he play's a video by tapping a button in the action bar. When that button is clicked I call VideoCastManager's isRemoteMediaLoaded() method, and set the track. I have verified that isRemoteMediaLoaded() returns true. Also the RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult has the SUCCESS status, fwiw.

Comment: Can you check to see if line breaks in your vtt file is CRLF or LF? Maybe you are running into this issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=340

Comment: .vtt files are being generated in a Go-app, and are deployed to App Engine (Unix). '\n' are being used for line breaks, and LF is thus used.

Comment: If you can share one of the files, I can try that in my environment

Comment: Uploaded my testing file here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c5bf0e9a7838bae587ed

Comment: Did you find out anything?

Comment: I tested your vtt file and it worked in my environment, although I had no cue what it was saying!). In your environment, take a look at the Network tab of the chrome debugger, see if chromecast is loading the VTT file at all or not.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I see no reference to the file in the Chrome debugger's Network tab.

Comment: Then in the chrome debugger, in the console, find where it shows the url for the vtt file (it should be part of the json for loading of the media) and click on that and see if it actually takes you to that file or not; something about the url or so is not correct in your environment

Comment: That works perfectly fine. I tried to host one of the .vtt files on Google Drive, but that made no difference. Here are the response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/vtt
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Thu, 28 Aug 2014 21:06:29 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Cache-Control: private
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
Transfer-Encoding: chunked


I don't see anything suspicious, but maybe you do?

Comment: I see that the mediaSessionId is 1 when the video starts playing, and is 2 after I've requested the active track to be set. Is this correct?

Comment: Are the mediaSessionId's supposed to be the same? If they are, have you got any idea why they might be different?